# Changing query based on multi-value parameter

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a multi value parameter from a report that will hide or show columns accordingly. The dataset calls the corresponding stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RandomProc @Server NVARCHAR(100)
AS

SELECT
    t1.Cluster,
    t2.Server,
    t2.ServerIP
FROM
    Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE 
    t1.Cluster LIKE '%' + @Server + '%' OR
    t2.Server LIKE '%' + @Server + '%' OR 
    t2.ServerIP LIKE '%' + @Server + '%'
```

If I were to untick Cluster from the report, in addition to the Cluster column being hidden from the report, t1.cluster should be removed from the SELECT and WHERE clause. And so on for other values.

Is this possible? Should this be done at the query level or through SSRS?

Writing multiple queries isn't feasible as there are too many options to pick from in the multi-value parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two additional parameters and add them to the query and SSRS to filter data set:

```
@Cluster NVARCHAR(100)
,@ServerIP NVARCHAR(100)
```

You could use dynamic SQL to add/remove columns in the SELECT; however, SSRS report will not be working properly if your columns disappear or appear.

Update:
Step by step how to setup conditional column visibility in SSRS:
http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/conditionally-setting-column-visibility-in-ssrs/